# Terminology - Difference between thread and process and how they manage DB connections

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, ruby

I've been working more with concurrency in Ruby recently, and I keep seeing various articles using "threads" and "process" interchangeably.

What are the actual definitions of these terms? Is a process composed of multiple threads?

Let's say I use a web server.

Am I correctly understanding the following?

1. Each web server *worker* is its own process. It has an individual listing in the Linux process list (`ps aux`) <sup>[PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block)</sup>.
2. Each *worker* has multiple *threads*. These threads share memory and another context because it's all really one process, but simulate the process doing multiple things at once.
3. Each *thread* has (at most) one connection to a Database which it uses to query or write data. It checks this connection out from a Connection Pool, which is a collection of connections available for use
4. Each *connection pool* applies to one *process*. So if my background job processor (e.g. Resque, Delayed Job, etc...) has a concurrency of "25" it means that each worker process gets up to 25 connections to distribute among its threads.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread

Comment: I don't know about Ruby. But your understanding is correct if it behaves as any other system I know of.